# addClass to label if checkbox is checked, even on page refresh

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How would I write the following in jQuery?:

```
When page load / (or "Continue" button is clicked, if makes more sense)
    Find input[type=checkbox] in each .block-container
        If input is checked
            add class to label
        If input is not checked
            remove class from label
```

I have a long line of checkboxes that follow this structure:

```
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="form-group wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox checkbox-418">
            <div class="checkbox wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox checkbox-418 checked_check">
                <label class="">
                    <input type="checkbox" aria-invalid="false" value="Lorem ipsum title" name="checkbox-418" novalidate="novalidate" class="garlic-auto-save" checked="checked">
                    Lorem ipsum title</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had a toggleClass on them to add a color to the label when it's clicked, and a fancy checkbox icon (with the checkbox itself moved offscreen) but when the page is refreshed the class isn't applied even if the checkbox is still checked.

So if the user refreshes the page, the checkboxes they checked will remain checked, but the visual indicator (color, fancy checkbox) will appear to them to be unchecked, so they'll check it again and wind up unchecking the check.

Thanks in advance.

Edit to add something I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select-action').on('click',function() {
        $('.block-container input').each(function() {
            if ($("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked')) {
                $(this).parent("label").addClass("symptomChecked");
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("empty_check").addClass("checked_check");
            } else {
                $("input").parent("label").removeClass("symptomChecked");
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("checked_check").addClass("empty_check");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: did you try anything, if tried share that

Comment: @ArunPJohny edited my post, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a change event handler which can be manually triggered on page load

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.block-container input[type="checkbox"]').on('change.symptom', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('symptomChecked', this.checked);
    $(this).closest('.checkbox').toggleClass('checked_check', this.checked).toggleClass('empty_check', !this.checked);
  }).trigger('change.symptom');
});
```

```css
.symptomChecked {
  color: green;
}
.empty_check {
  background-color: grey;
}
.checked_check {
  border: 1 px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="form-group wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox checkbox-418">
      <div class="checkbox wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox checkbox-418 checked_check">
        <label class="">
          <input type="checkbox" aria-invalid="false" value="Lorem ipsum title" name="checkbox-418" novalidate="novalidate" class="garlic-auto-save" checked="checked">Lorem ipsum title</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="form-group wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox checkbox-418">
      <div class="checkbox wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox checkbox-418">
        <label class="">
          <input type="checkbox" aria-invalid="false" value="Lorem ipsum title" name="checkbox-418" novalidate="novalidate" class="garlic-auto-save">Lorem ipsum title</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="form-group wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox checkbox-418">
      <div class="checkbox wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox checkbox-418">
        <label class="">
          <input type="checkbox" aria-invalid="false" value="Lorem ipsum title" name="checkbox-418" novalidate="novalidate" class="garlic-auto-save">Lorem ipsum title</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this toggles the style on change. I need the style to be remain even on page refresh. Currently, the checked state itself is preserved, but the style disappears.

Comment: `.trigger('change.symptom')` should trigger the change event on page load which should assign the proper styling

Comment: It's not assigning styling on page load for me. Could garlic.js (session storage) be affecting this at all? Not sure why it's not working on my end.

Comment: @bunnycode if you are using session storage to update the checked status, then `$('.block-container input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('change.symptom');` has to be done after updating the state

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but could you please clarify what you mean by "after updating the state"? Right now it does sequentially come after garlic.js, is that what you mean?

Comment: Your code works! I just needed to swap out $(document).ready for $(window).on("load",function() { - thank you very much!!